# How would I find multiple means from one column?

Tags: r, mean

I have a data frame (cf) with 9 variables and about 30k observations. I need to find the average of variable dem_vote_pct based on variable state, and each state has hundreds of observations, so I somehow have to find 50 averages by isolating specific rows in one column. I've tried using the filter and select functions but I'm not sure how to use them without writing a large chunk of code listing all 50 states.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to write this code without having to manually pick out all 50 states?

Comment: Please share at least an excerpt of your data. You can use `dput ()` to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I don't have any data to work on, I think what you want to achieve is to compute averages by a specific grouping variable (i.e., US states). Below, I created a solution using the mighty **data.table** package. Please, read more about this package [here](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/).

Since I don't have the data, I only simulate a data.table with 100 rows (`N`) and 2 columns (`dem_vote_pct` and `states`). Also, I am not assuming that `dem_vote_pct` sums to 1 by each state. Please note that the `state` variable only contains three US states for brevity.

**data.table** is incredibly flexible and easy to use. The syntax is a bit different compared to other packages, but I believe that it is fairly intuitive.

After replicating your data, all I do is define a variable `avg_vote` as the mean of `dem_vote_pct` by the grouping variable `state`. You can see how intuitive the codes looks like.

Please have a look below.

```r
library(data.table)

N <- 100
USstates <- c("Arizona", "California", "Illinois")

set.seed(1970)
dt <- data.table( dem_vote_pct = runif(N),
                  state = sample( USstates, size = N, replace = TRUE ) )
head(dt)
#>    dem_vote_pct      state
#> 1:   0.15312818   Illinois
#> 2:   0.82434781   Illinois
#> 3:   0.15324174   Illinois
#> 4:   0.01408015   Illinois
#> 5:   0.82657713 California
#> 6:   0.89392581    Arizona

avg_votes <- dt[ , .( avg_vote = mean( dem_vote_pct ) ), by = state ]
avg_votes
#>         state  avg_vote
#> 1:   Illinois 0.4757793
#> 2: California 0.5600203
#> 3:    Arizona 0.5906794
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Is this what you want to get?